# How can I look up IIS site id in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, installation, wmi

I am writing an installer class for my web service. In many cases when I use WMI  (e.g. when creating virtual directories) I have to know the siteId to provide the correct metabasePath to the site, e.g.:

```
metabasePath is of the form "IIS://<servername>/<service>/<siteID>/Root[/<vdir>]"
for example "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root"
```

How can I look it up programmatically in C#, based on the name of the site (e.g. for "Default Web Site")?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how to get it by name.  You can modify as needed.

```
public int GetWebSiteId(string serverName, string websiteName)
{
  int result = -1;

  DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(
                      string.Format("IIS://{0}/w3svc", serverName));

  foreach (DirectoryEntry site in w3svc.Children)
  {
    if (site.Properties["ServerComment"] != null)
    {
      if (site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value != null)
      {
        if (string.Compare(site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString(), 
                             websiteName, false) == 0)
        {
            result = int.Parse(site.Name);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: On my system I had to update the above with the following to get it to compile "result = Convert.ToInt32(site.Name);"

Answer (score 5):

You can search for a site by inspecting the `ServerComment` property belonging to children of the metabase path `IIS://Localhost/W3SVC` that have a `SchemaClassName` of `IIsWebServer`.

The following code demonstrates two approaches:

```
string siteToFind = "Default Web Site";

// The Linq way
using (DirectoryEntry w3svc1 = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC"))
{
    IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> children = 
          w3svc1.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>();

    var sites = 
        (from de in children
         where
          de.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer" &&
          de.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString() == siteToFind
         select de).ToList();
    if(sites.Count() > 0)
    {
        // Found matches...assuming ServerComment is unique:
        Console.WriteLine(sites[0].Name);
    }
}

// The old way
using (DirectoryEntry w3svc2 = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC"))
{

    foreach (DirectoryEntry de in w3svc2.Children)
    {
        if (de.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer" && 
            de.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString() == siteToFind)
        {
            // Found match
            Console.WriteLine(de.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the `ServerComment` property has been used (IIS MMC forces its used) and is unique.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the best way, but here is a way :

1. loop through all the sites under "IIS://servername/service"
2. for each of the sites check if the name is "Default Web Site" in your case
3. if true then you have your site id

Example :

```
Dim oSite As IADsContainer
Dim oService As IADsContainer
Set oService = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC")
For Each oSite In oService
    If IsNumeric(oSite.Name) Then
        If oSite.ServerComment = "Default Web Site" Then
            Debug.Print "Your id = " & oSite.Name
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private static string FindWebSiteByName(string serverName, string webSiteName)
{
    DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/W3SVC");
    foreach (DirectoryEntry site in w3svc.Children)
    {
        if (site.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer"
            && site.Properties["ServerComment"] != null
            && site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value != null
            && string.Equals(webSiteName, site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return site.Name;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: The string returned can be parsed as an int if that is necessary. My guess is that in most cases you don't really need it returned as an 'int' as you will use it to make a URI.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static ManagementObject GetWebServerSettingsByServerComment(string serverComment)
        {
            ManagementObject returnValue = null;

            ManagementScope iisScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\MicrosoftIISv2", new ConnectionOptions());
            iisScope.Connect();
            if (iisScope.IsConnected)
            {
                ObjectQuery settingQuery = new ObjectQuery(String.Format(
                    "Select * from IIsWebServerSetting where ServerComment = '{0}'", serverComment));

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(iisScope, settingQuery);
                ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

                if (results.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject manObj in results)
                    {
                        returnValue = manObj;

                        if (returnValue != null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: Does it work with IIS version <7? Unfortunately I am stuck with Win2k3

Comment: @Helephant, where find apppools using this method ?? in IIS 6 ??